# check for a sequence of words form a text file saved in string vector c++

Tags: c++

I have a text file of parsed c++ program as below (consider all lines as content of .txt file)

```
element
unit
element
cpp:include
pcdata
#
element
cpp:directive
pcdata
include
element
cpp:file
pcdata
<iostream>
element
using
pcdata
using 
element
namespace
pcdata
namespace 
element
name
pcdata
std
pcdata
;
element
class
pcdata
class 
element
name
pcdata
Person
element
block
pcdata
{
element
private
element
public
pcdata
public:

element
decl_stmt
element
decl
element
type
element
name
pcdata
string
element
name
pcdata
profession
pcdata
;
element
decl_stmt
element
decl
element
type
element
name
pcdata
int
element
name
pcdata
age
pcdata
;
element
constructor
element
name
pcdata
Person
element
parameter_list
pcdata
()
element
member_init_list
pcdata
: 
element
call
element
name
pcdata
profession
element
argument_list
pcdata
(
element
argument
element
expr
element
literal
pcdata
......
......
```

This file is a parsed using srcml tool and removed xml tags.

1-i need to read file line by line (Or word by word is also fine for me) and compare it with string values defined in my code. For example, check a word pattern like if any word read from file is **"element"** then check if next word is **"class"** again check if next word is **"pcdata"** again if next word is **"class"** again if next word is **"element"** again if next word is **"name"** again if next word is **"pcdata"** then save next word read from file i.e. in this case **"person"**(this is in line number 29 to 36 ) to some vector/array.

2- Do step 1 within a block i.e. if read value is **"{"** from file then look for pattern like mentioned in point 1, till **"}"** occurs save it for that block and continue.

my headder file is xmlVector.h as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  
#include <fstream> 
#include <vector>   
    class xmlVector
{
public:
void browseFile(); // Read file and load it to vector
void printVector(); // Print loaded vector  
typedef vector < string > vector_str; // Define vector to store the File.
vector<string>::iterator vec_it; // used in traversal  

public: 
 string line;
 string class_name;
 string &temp;

};

class classList : public xmlVector
{
 public:
 string list_classes();     
};
```

my xmlVector.cpp is

```
#include "xmlVector.h" 
using namespace std; 
void xmlVector::browseFile() // Create vector from parsed data
{
vector_str vect;

 ifstream code_File ("Test.txt", ios::in);
 while (getline(code_File, line))
 {
    vect.push_back(line);   // add the line to the vector

 }
    }



 void xmlVector::printVector() // Print values in vector_str
 {
 for (string s : vect)
 { 
 cout << s << endl;
 }
 }



string classList::list_classes()
{
for (str_it = vector_str.begin(); str_it !=vector_str.end(); str_it++)
 {
                       temp = &str_it;
            string element1 = "element";
 if(*temp.compare(element1) == 0){

                     str_it = begin()+1;
                       temp = &str_it;
            string element2 = "class";        
 if(*temp.compare(element2) == 0){

                     str_it = begin()+2;
                       temp = &str_it;
            string element3 = "pcdata";       
 if(*temp.compare(element3) == 0){

                     str_it = begin()+3;
                       temp = &str_it;
            string element4 = "class";        
 if(*temp.compare(element4) == 0){

                     str_it = begin()+4;
                       temp = &str_it;
            string element5 = "element";          
 if(*temp.compare(element5) == 0){

                     str_it = begin()+5;
                       temp = &str_it;
            string element6 = "name";         
 if(*temp.compare(element6) == 0){

                     str_it = begin()+6;
                       temp = &str_it;
            string element7 = "pcdata";       
 if(*temp.compare(element7) == 0){                    
                 class_name = *temp;
          cout << "class name = " << class_name;
          } 
      }
      }
      }
      }
      }    
    }
   }
  }
```

My main.cpp is

```
 include <iostream> // Std Library
 #include "xmlVector.h" 
 #include <string>  
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 xmlVector readXmlVector;
 readXmlVector.browseFile();
 readXmlVector.printVector();
 //cout << "Printed Successfully in the file " << endl;
 classList classes;
 classes.list_classes(); 
 }
```

I need to save the names of all classes and their member functions present in input file "Test.txt". I am stuck as I'm unable to search for the mentioned pattern in the vector.

Kindly help me to iterate through the vector and comparing string literals present in vector through each iteration save the next value somewhere (may be a vector) after a pattern matches.

Comment: That's kind of what a *parser* does: It reads "tokens" one by one to see if it can match special sequences. Do some more research about [*parsing computer languages*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages).

Comment: All i need to know is how to compare some string values to items present in a vector string at subsequent positions. 'vector <string>:: iterator it points to vec.begin()' then how to compare value at 'vec.begin()' to some string '"some1"' and if it matches how to move to 'vec.begin()+1' and comapre that value to another string '"another"'.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the vector of strings with `it` and hold the reference sequence in '`Sequence`'. The for a given position call `if( sequence_starts_here(it, vector.end(), ReferenceSequence) ) return true;`

```
bool
sequence_starts_here(vector<string>::iterator*      it, 
                     vector<string>::const_iterator itEnd, 
                     const vector<string>&          Sequence) 
{
   for(vector<string>::const_iterator itStr = Sequence.begin(); 
       itStr != Sequence.end() && it != itEnd && *it == *itStr; 
       ++itStr, ++it);

   return itStr == Sequence.end();
}
```